# Vue Router Navigation Guard Dynamic Import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I want to dynamically import *data* from **component file** to **router file** and allow `next()` depending upon value of imported *data*.

in **App.vue** I'm triggering `this.$router.push({name: "Dashboard"})` when *data* `authenticated: false` changes to `true`. I'm triggering it with `watch`.

Problem is, **router file** will always receive original value `false` even with dynamic importing.

---

**App.vue**

```
watch: {
      authenticated(){
         console.log(this.authenticated)             //Outputs 'true'
         this.$router.push({name: 'Dashboard'});     //Triggers routing
      }
   }
```

---

**router file (index.js)**

```
{
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      component: Dashboard,
      beforeEnter(to, from, next){
         (async ()=>{
            const mod = await import('../view/App.vue');  //Dynamic import
            let result = mod.default.data().auth;         //Access 'authenticated' value from App.vue
            console.log(result);                          //Output is 'false', but it should be 'true'
            result ? next() : next({name: 'Login'});
         })()
      }
}
```

---

I tried many different `async` methods as well but nothing worked.

Comment: You're accessing `auth` not `authenticated`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `In-Component Guard` in your `App.vue` as specified [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) and remove the authentication login from `router` file:

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    if (to.name === 'Dashboard' && this.authenticated) {
        next();
    }
    else {
        next({ name: 'Login' });
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is based on the scope of question you've asked. The authentication logic can get very diverse depending on the project structure. I'd suggest to store the `authenticated` variable in `vuex` so that every component that requires authentication can access that variable

Comment: Thank you for answering. I declared `beforeRouteEnter(from, to, next)` in `App.vue` but it's not triggering. `App.vue` is where `<router-link>` for Dashboard is located. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Just store the `authenticated` variable in `vuex` because you might use this variable somewhere else too to protect different routes. Then you can use `authenticated` variable in `beforeEnter` as you have mentioned in your question like this: `store.state.authenticated`. See [this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html)

Comment: I didn't learn Vuex yet but I guess I'll have to hang on to this issue until I learn it. Thank you for answering.